# Using Web API Map Controller Actions to Class Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

As the title suggests, I'd like to programmatically create controllers during application start (or at some point) that are generated from non-controller classes.

for instance the following class would map to something like.

/api/MyClass/Method1

/api/MyClass/Method2

/api/MyClass/Method3

```
public class MyClass
{
    public object Method1()
    {
    }

    public object Method2()
    {
    }

    public object Method3()
    {
    }
}
```

I realize that I could create the controller exactly like this, but I was hoping I could reflect the object and programmatically create the actions.

Is this possible?

Comment: I believe this is already what's happening in the regular routing (non attribute routing) as long as your controller inherit from `ApiController`. If your class isn't an `ApiController`, you would need to either make it so, or emit a wrapper controller at runtime which, depending on your ease with that kind of solution, can be painful.

Comment: I'm looking to do your second suggestion, where I would generate a wrapper controller at runtime, that I could then dump a whole bunch of methods into. Have you ever seen this done before? Or links to examples?

Comment: There are examples around, look for anything around IL Emit or the general concept of creating a type through reflection.